# Character count of textfile

Tags: java, while-loop, counter, bufferedreader, println

I'm looking to perform a character count on an all lowercase character .txt file in java, at present the print method end up blank when trying to print the count. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file1 = new File("newfile.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file1));
    System.out.println("Relative Letter Frequency");

    int ch;
    char i = 0;
    // Declare 26 char counting
    int[] count = new int[26];
    //Loop through the file char
    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
    i = (char) ch;
        if (i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')
        count[i - 'a']++;
    }

    //Print loop
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
        //Print formatting so each letter is represented on
        //a new line with correct spacing
        System.out.printf("%c %d \n", j + 'a', count[j]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    in.close();
}

int Counter(File file,String Charset) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File("newfile.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file1));

        int Count = 0;
        while (in.read() > -1){
            Count++;

        }
        System.out.println(Count);
        in.close();     
        return Count;
    }
}
```

I've tried to change the loop for the character counter, but still to no avail

```
            public void Counter(File file,String Charset) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File("newfile.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        int CH;
        char k = 0;
        int [] Count = new int [1];
        while ((CH = in.read()) != -1){
            k = (char) CH;
            if (k >= 'a' && k <='z')
            Count [k]++;    
        }
    System.out.println(Count[k]);
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you divide the filesize by the bytesize of a character?

Comment: Works fine for me, what exactly is the problem? @Discipol `in.read()` reads bytes, so it should divide ;)

Comment: @Discipol if dividing the file size by bytesize of a character this would include the spaces and new line markers also I think.

Comment: Are you sure you just want to check for lower-case characters? What about `Character.isLetter(ch)` or something like that?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just count the number of individual characters in the first method and then display for each letter which works fine, but I then need a total of all the letters and then compare that to the total number so giving a percentage of what each letter represents in the text. The dividing by total number of characters would work but I can't include non-alphabetic ones.

Comment: @Matthias no the fiel si already all lower case with punctuation etc. removed.

Comment: Would be good to state that in your question. So we have a file with all lowercase text, but spaces and newlines in an unknown encoding, or can we assume one? Why not read the whole thing as a String, or at least line by line. A lot easier than messing with the bytes you get plus you can set the encoding of the file.

Comment: @Matthias Fairpoint, duly noted. It would be a lot easier to use String, but the file is huge and would end up being very slow, and unfortunately I have to read out to a new file. Cheers anyway.

Comment: @user3008724 Yeah I didn't notice the need to avoid blanks & stuff. You can't help but to pass through it :(

Answer (score 2):

Since I slowly realize what you need, I have adapted your code to show two ways of how to do it.

Here is an example which reads the file twice. The 1st time it counts characters by reading line by line using a `BufferedReader`.

The 2nd solution which is directly below reads the stuff byte by byte and counts characters as you probably try to do.

```
package snippet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Snippet {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Sum: " + counter(new File("newfile.txt")));
  }

  public static int counter(File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    int[] counter = new int[26];
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
          counter[c - 'a']++;
        }
      }
    }

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    int read;
    while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
      if ((read >= 'a') && (read <= 'z')) {
        counter[read - 'a']++;
      }
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (int count : counter) {
      System.out.println(count);
      result += count;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound incredibly stupid, but why not just use the length of file.ToString?
Are you trying to skip spaces and carriage returns or something?
Was just looking for some clarification of what you are attempting to do here...

Or simply loop through each SubString and create a function to return if it's "A" or "a" etc..
I'm not a C coder, but I use to do some work in C++ so, I'll try to outline it for you in the language I understand...

```
Public Function GetIsCharacter(ByVal sCharacter As String) As Boolean

 If sCharacter = "A" Then ' etc...
   Return True
 End If

' else...
Return False

End Function
```